# Express Rest API server(backend) having multiple signup/signin technique. How do you maintain user not being duplicated and signin?

Tags: rest, express, mobile

If user login with username/password or sign in with google, that user should have same data and profile if he chooses to signup first or signup later with same email. How do you manage these thing in User Model creation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a relationship of usertype and checking the way user gets created and adding it to usertype. like 'local', 'google' ,'twitter' etc.